# Discrepancies in Unit Price at Order Page and PDF Invoice when changed using Woocommerce OpenPOS

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I have two plugins installed in Wordpress

1. Woocommerce OpenPOS (v6.2.0)
2. WP Overnight - PDF Invoices & Packing Slips for WooCommerce (v3.7.1)

Issue : When using Woocommerce OpenPOS's POS Dashboard, you can change Unit Price of any item before clicking on "Pay" (placing order). For example, one item's default unit price is $8. Using OpenPOS, I changed its unit price to $6. When order is generated, it correctly displays (on admin panel) edited unit price from $8 to $6. However, generated PDF invoice still shows default price.

Here's an example of Order ID page shown on Admin panel. It correctly displays edited pricing.
[image]

Here's a screenshot of PDF invoice which shows correct total, but default unit price, not edited one.
[image]

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Easier Solution.

1. Download & Install Addon : PDF Invoices & Packing Slips for WooCommerce - Professional

2. Edit PDF Invoice using Plugin's Built-in "Customizer"

3. Add "Price" tab and select "Single Price" in it. Don't use "Regular Price" Tab, because that's what was causing this issue.

That's it!